# Is it possible to have Visual Studio produce a different filename in the Debug folder from the Release folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to have Visual Studio produce a different filename in the `bin\Debug` folder from the `bin\Release` folder?

Ideally I'd like to see `bin\Debug\Application.Debug.exe` and `bin\Release\Application.exe`.

Perhaps there is a script I can add? I'm just tired of doing this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suitable post build step would be this:

```
if NOT $(ConfigurationName)==Debug goto done
del $(ProjectName).debug.exe
copy $(TargetFileName) $(ProjectName).Debug.exe
:done
```

(Assuming $(ProjectName) is the same as the executable name without the .exe suffix.)

It doesn't need to be in a batch file; paste it straight in to the post build settings.

Originally, instead of the copy I was just renaming the .exe like so:

```
ren $(TargetFileName) $(ProjectName).Debug.exe
```

But that had a really annoying drawback - when you go to debug, it says the .exe is missing (which it is of course). So I ended up just making a copy.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a batch file in the post build event, that will rename your Application.exe to Application.Debug.exe.

Comment: Will this affect my ability to debug within VS?

Comment: Try it, it takes about 30 seconds to find out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe VS has that funcitonality baked in, but you could easily craft a post build event for debug build to rename your file from *Application.exe* to **Application.Debug.exe**

Comment: Will this affect my ability to debug within VS?

Comment: @michael.mankus I believe it will as VS won't be able to find `Application.exe`, another thing you can do if you want to still be able to debug is make a copy of the file with the new name, but you'll end up with two copies of the same file with different names